# Cannot run application as admin user with Admin privilege

Tags: azure-active-directory, active-directory, intune

Recently I started work in a new company with a new Dell Laptop, the original OS was windows 10, and I upgraded the system to windows 11.

Like my other colleagues, I created an admin account in the AD with precisely the same group membership.

Microsoft Intune manages my machine.

I can connect and run applications on the servers as my admin user account with no issue, but on my laptop, I can not run applications as an admin user. My college can run the application as their admin user on my machine.

Do any ideas or suggestions on how can I fix this issue?

- Checked all configuration and access in Azure and Microsoft Intune, and AD

Comment: Your admin account would have to be in the Administrators group on your computer. If it already is, then reboot. If it's not and it should be, then your organization may have a process to make that happen. I don't think anyone here could help you.

Comment: I don't think is related to the Administrator group on my machine because my colleague can run the application; I noticed when I use a full-domain\ admin -user, I can run the application as an administrator instead of using the UPN format